# Why are the parameterizations of the circle in cartesian coordinates defined in open intervals?

Tags: parametric

The parameterization of the circle in rectangular coordinates is given by the  the following functions

$$
y = g_1(x) = \sqrt{(1-x^2)} \\
y = g_2(x) = -\sqrt{(1-x^2)} \\
x = g_3(y) = \sqrt{(1-y^2)} \\
x = g_4(y) = -\sqrt{(1-y^2)} 
$$

for $-1<x<1$ and $-1<y<1$. However the final two (or the first two) are only required because the interval where $x$ (or $y$) is defined is open. Why does that interval need to be open?

Comment: This question is a little confusing. By the interval being open, do you mean interval for each equation alone or by both combined such that $(x=...,y=....)$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was referring to the intervals $-1< x < 1$ and $-1<y<1$.

Comment: I found that the intervals are closed as long as the output is defined. Yet this question is out of my understanding so it would great if someonelse can answer this.

Comment: You don´t need the intervals be open if you require just the corresponding values for, say, $y$ in the two first equations. Another thing is if you asked about other properties such as differentiability because you can see geometrically that the slope at $(0,1)$ shows trouble but clearly $y=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrizations are usually taken to be *regular*, i.e., continuously-differentiable with non-zero derivative.

The notion of differentiability at endpoints is a dicey matter in general, but for the functions $x \mapsto \pm\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}$ the problem is blunt: There's no differentiable extension to $[-1, 1]$, since the graphs have vertical tangents at the endpoints.

Comment: I knew it had to be something like that! Thanks.